# Visual Studio 2015 Cordova Ionic 2 not updating html files on build

Tags: cordova, ionic2, visual-studio-cordova

I'm running Visual Studio 2015 with Apache Cordova and Ionic 2.

If I update any of the `html` or `ts` files in `app/pages` the ripple emulator app refreshes (so detecting the updates), but the app content is still the same.  Only when I update the `www/build/pages` files does the content update.

It doesn't seem to matter how many times I build / clean / rebuild, the only way I can update the app content is to amend the files in `build` rather than `app`.

Any ideas?  Surely I should be updating `app/pages` and seeing the updates propagated to `www/build/pages` automatically, or at least on build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite scouring the internet and nearly going back to Ionic version 1 (as the lack of build made Ionic version 2 unusable, in version 1 you edit the files directly in the `www` folder) it turns out the solution was in the `Project_Readme.html` file.  (Who ever reads instructions?! ;-) :-D)

The issue seemed to be connected with Gulp that handles the build (`Gulpfile.js`).  By navigating to View → Other Windows → Task Runner Explorer this seems to open the Gulp build details, and for some reason having this window open seemed to trigger the proper build from `app` to `www`.

Comment: I did have run the "watch" task from the gulp window to start triggering on changes, which somehow makes sense. Actually: the readme also mentions this now.

Answer (score 2):

You may also need to add the "watch"-script manually to the package.json file. It was missing in my version of the Ionic templates for Visual Studio.

```html
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "watch": "ionic-app-scripts watch"
  },
```

Now you can add it to the Project Open bindings as per their screen-shot in the readme-file. (Close / Open the project)